# Generate entity in symfony 4 (methods)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

when I tried to run the command `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities App:Center` in symfony 4.0.6 I get this error:

> Can't find base path for "App\Entity\Center" (path:
>   "/home/USER/foo/bar/src/Entity",
>   destination: "/home/USER/foo/bar/src/Entity").

**the `Center` is my entity name!**

how can I fix this?

Comment: Where you trying to generate a class?! Or to refresh one?

Comment: @Preciel In the root of project directory I run this command and my entities stored in src/Entity/EntityName.php

Comment: This doesn't answer my current question... As the two commands are closes, I'm asking you if you were trying to generate an entity, and trying to refresh an existing one to do the getters/setters

Comment: @Preciel Oh - I'm sorry I want to generate getter and setter methods (refresh) - when I try to use phpstrom can't create addElement and etc.

Comment: Have you trying to clean dev cache?! Sometimes it prevent you from refresh... Is your project a new one?! Are you sure that files permissions are the good ones?! Are you in the good directory?! (Sorry, just checking various things as they the most commons)

Comment: @Preciel I cleaned the dev cache and run it again but I get this error again and the file permissions are -rw-rw-rw- with the user and group USER and my project is new not updated from symfony 3

Comment: user and group seems wrong... by default, web user is `www-data` Did you change apache/nginx user?

Comment: @Preciel I changed the Center Entity user and group to www-data ( apache) and not solved

Comment: That not the right way to proceed... Can you run this in console please: `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` and tell me which users are shown

Comment: @Preciel this is output: https://paste.ofcode.org/wTF72qG4KtpEWjfVqibL8H

Comment: Last question, what is your project path?

Comment: @Preciel at this directory: `/home/alireza/Projects/www/Dornash/1.1.0/Project`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine developers are deprecating the generation commands for Symfony 4. The reason why it doesn't work for you is because the command is hardwired to find the destination directory under 
`projectRoot/src/{namespace}/{App}Bundle/Entity/{Center.php}`
but the Symfony 4 directory structure is different than that, hence it cannot find it. If you are dead-set on using the command, you could probably extend it and create your own, in which you could change the destination path(s) for your entities. You can just skip the command part and generate getters and setters on your own.

Doctrine issue: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/729

Symfony issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/8893

From the maintainers of Doctrine:
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/790

Comment: oh - it's too bad but this is so hard to make addElement, removeElement, and etc. methods. I made my getter and setter with phpstrom generate but I don't have an idea how to do for other methods

Comment: addElement and removeElement methods are for when you have associations with your Entity. Check up demo projects on github, symfony has them, and see how they are handled there and use it in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

So, from the various questions, I think your first problem is files permissions...

Meanwhile, you need to first correct your files permissions.
Here is how to do it.

```
chown /home/alireza/Projects/www/ www-data:www-data /
find /home/alireza/Projects/www/ -type d -exec chmod 0755 "{}" \;
find /home/alireza/Projects/www/ -type f -exec chmod 0664 "{}" \;
find /home/alireza/Projects/www/ -type d -exec chmod g-s "{}" \;
find /home/alireza/Projects/www/ -type d -exec chmod g+s "{}" \;
```

As I assume that `www/` is where all your projects are stored, I stopped the path at the `www/` folder. It will thus correct files permissions for all of your projects.

Also, make sure to add your current user to the `www-data` group.

```
usermod -a -G www-data user_name
```

Try this, and tell us if you still have your problem.

Comment: np @A.Seddighi... Though I don't think that will be the end of yours problems... Make sure to check domagoj03 answer, might prove useful