# Symfony 3.4 - blank page after deploying on server

Tags: php, symfony, deployment

I've made simple page in Symfony 3.4 and it is working fine locally both on dev and prod envs. I've decided to put it on my server, but i don't have ssh access there, so i had to do it by ftp. I've changed "web" folder to "public_html/web" (still working locally), made cache:clear, archived whole project and put it on server.

But when i go to mypage/public_html/web/ i got only blank page. When i go to web/app_dev.php i see message that i'm not allowed to access it.

I installed new symfony 3.2 project with fantastico and it's working. I tried even to put whole my project to public_html as fantastico did, but it didn't help.

var/cache and var/logs have perms 777 (without very deep subfolders because without ssh i had to change it manually for every tier)

When i put test.php with echo to web folder it works. I can't do shell_exec on my server.

I exported my database on server but i had to rename it with "servername_" prefix. Could it be cause of this problem? I tried to change parameters.yml with new host name and user but it's still the same. Does it needs to clear cache again after change? I'm changing it on server so i cant clear cache there with command.

What should i do to make it work? I am sitting on it second evening and i am still in same point.

.........

EDIT:

I tried to deploy it on another hosting - also without shell, this time it's free hosting. After putting it on ftp i get such error:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface' not found in /profiles/r/ra/rad/radioaktywnyja/radio-test.cba.pl/domowy-budzet/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Bundle/BundleInterface.php on line 24
```

I can't find what does that error means and how to get rid of it. Anyone can help?

Here is that project on github
https://github.com/Radioaktywnyja/domowy-budzet

Comment: [Look at my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471207/6711360) for file permissions

Comment: @Preciel Hi. Sorry for so late answer but it was Easter holidays and I was offline. I looked at your answer but i don't know how to do it without SSH access. Is it possible by FTP or Cpanel?

Comment: Hello, nope, it's not possible via FTP... As for Cpanel, I do not know if it's possible. If you can access shell as root from it, then you should be able to do it...

Comment: Unfortunately i can't. So there is no possibility to run symfony on server without shell access?

Comment: Well, there should be, but I'm not familiar with servers which you don't have control over